# Why is ANTLR not printing set of tokens correctly?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am testing to see if ANTLR-4.7.1 is working properly by using a sample, provided by my professor, to match these results for the same printed set of tokens:

```
% java  -jar ./antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar HelloExample.g4
% javac  -cp antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar HelloExample*.java
% java -cp .:antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig HelloExample greeting helloworld.greeting -tokens
[@0,0:4='Hello',<1>,1:0]
[@1,6:10='World',<3>,1:6]
[@2,12:12='!',<2>,1:12]
[@3,14:13='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
(greeting Hello World !)
```

However, after getting to the 3rd command, my output was instead:

```
[@0,0:4='Hello',<'Hello'>,1:0]
[@1,6:10='World',<Name>,1:6]
[@2,12:12='!',<'!'>,1:12]
[@3,13:12='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:13]
```

In my output, there are no numbers inside < >, which I believe should be defined from the HelloExample.tokens file that contain:

```
Hello=1
Bang=2
Name=3
WS=4
'Hello'=1
'!'=2
```

I get no error information and antlr seemed to have generated all the files I needed, so I don't know where I should be looking to resolve this, please help. And I'm not sure if it'll be of use, but my working directory started with `helloworld.greeting` and `HelloExample.g4` and final directory now contains

```
helloworld.greeting
HelloExample.g4
HelloExample.interp
HelloExample.tokens
HelloExampleBaseListener.class
HelloExampleBaseListener.java
HelloExampleLexer.class
HelloExampleLexer.inerp
HelloExampleLexer.java
HelloExampleLexer.tokens
HelloExampleListener.class
HelloExampleListener.java
HelloExampleParser$GreetingContext.class
HelloExampleParser.class
HelloExampleParser.java
```

Comment: That's all working as expected. You did nothing wrong. There were a couple of changes to the way Antlr's testrig prints tokens over the years, and I suspect your prof is using a much older version of the testrig than you are.

Answer (score 0):

As rici already pointed out in the comments, getting the actual rule names instead of their numbers in the token output is a feature and shouldn't worry you.

In order to get the `(greeting Hello World !)` output at the end, you'll want to add the `-tree` flag after `-tokens`.